# What is .EAppxBundle Compared to .AppxBundle

Tags: extract, xbox, appx, makeappx

I wiresharked a download on my Xbox one, It was GtaV
And i got a .EAppxBundle Not a .appx or .AppxBundle.
Anyone know how to open these/convert them? 
(Removing the E does not work)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an [encrypted appx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/appxpkg/make-appx-package--makeappx-exe-#using-app-packager), that's why simply removing the *e* did not work.

Only if you have the key used to encrypt the package you can extract its contents.

You can find more details about appx encryption/decryption in the linked article, just search for "encrypt".

Comment: Thank you, Is there any way of decrypting it?

Comment: The decrypt command line is mentioned in the MSDN article, but you would need the key used to encrypt it, so short answer is no.